# Is the following version of that problem NP-complete?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity

Suppose $G_0, G_1, ..., G_n$ is a sequence of graphs. Let’s call it a *composition sequence* iff $G_0$ has subgraphs $A_1, ... , A_n$ such that $A_i = G_i \forall i \leq n$ and their union is exactly $G_0$.

Suppose an arbitrary finite sequence of graphs is given by its length and adjacency matrices of its elements. Then it is known, that the problem of determining, whether it is a *composition sequence* is NP-complete.

However, what will happen if we restrict the problem to the case, when $G_0$ is known to be a complete graph? Is this particular case of the problem still NP-complete?

Comment: It's still at least as hard as graph isomorphism (but it could be harder). Do you have a citation for the general composition sequence problem being NP-complete?